# Swift storyboard - Creating a segue in MapView using calloutaccessorycontroltapped disclosure button

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, segue, xcode-storyboard

In my MapView, I have several MKAnnotation pins that each have the viewFor configured to show the small popup with the disclosure "I" button on the right.

Now I am trying to find a way to create a segue from hitting the disclosure "I" button in the popup - I see that this can be done with the

```
func mapView(... calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)
```

**However, because in storyboard the MKAnnotation pins of course do not show up, I don't know how to use the control-drag method of creating the segue and getting the corresponding segue ID.**

My workaround - I basically instantiate the other view controller that I wish to segue towards and switch to that new view whenever the "I" button is pressed

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let settingVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SetNotifPageID") as! SetNotificationViewController
    self.present(settingVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

**But is there a better way to perform this, say from within storyboard, or maybe with a more correct approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the segue, in the storyboard, drag from the ViewController icon on one view controller to the view area of the second view controller.

[image]

Then call `performSegue(identifier:sender)` from `mapView(_:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:)`.

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdFromTheStoryboard", sender: nil)
}
```

Configure your destination view controller from `prepare(for:sender:)`.

```swift
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let viewController = segue.destination as? SetNotificationViewController {
            // configure your view controller
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The segue performs correctly, but I notice that the prepare() method in the destination VC is not being called, despite setting the title in the Storyboard. Any ideas to anything I may have forgotten to set?

Comment: Ah never mind, I realized I was setting up the prepare function in the wrong view controller